# What url do I enter for an ajax request from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to write a JSON file with an ajax request from javascript. I am confused about the URL. I've never done anything server side before and I am using WAMP server 3.0.6 to host my work in progress project. I am wondering what URL I would enter. Right now I have "http://localhost/testproject/test.php" but it doesn't seem to be working. I have literally no experience or idea about server side or where to start. I need to send a JSON file to the web server which is self-hosted which is then stored to be retrieved later. What URL do I need to use, and what do I need to set up?

Comment: All I can do is to direct you to [this article](https://www.xul.fr/scripts/ajax-php.php) :-)

Comment: Since it's not working, it would be helpful if you would show us your code, so we can see why it's not working. Show us both javascript and php.

Comment: Yeah, what does test.php return ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use any url you want like your test.php
2. to write a file with php you can use the

   file_put_contents("data.json", '{"some": "data"}');

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php